# localStorage, does token have to string or not?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, local-storage

I'm currently watching a course about MERNG stack and i saw that, when we put the token of the user in the local Storage to login or register, we didn't save the token as a string, we just save it, we didn't use JSON.Stringify, can someone explain me if it's necessesary to save information as string or it's just a best practice that everybody else do ?

Comment: localStorage _only_ stores string values, it can’t store anything else. Either your access token was a string value to begin with, or if it is some sort of object, then it must provide a  toString method for implicit conversion when it gets put into a string context.

Comment: I get it, thank you !